# Passing custom parameter to Audio Unit kAudioUnitSubType_HighPassFilter cutoff by UISlider

Tags: core-audio

What I would like to achieve is change cutoff parameter programmatically by sending value from `UISlider` example 1 (normal state):

```
 Float32 highPassFilterCutoff = 4000.0;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetParameter(_auHighPassFilter,
                                 kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                 0,
                                 highPassFilterCutoff,
                                 0),
           "Coulnd't set kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency ");
```

What I want:

```
NSLog(@"cutOffSlider.value in effect %f",cutOffslider.value );
   Float32 highPassFilterCutoff = cutOffslider.value;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetParameter(_auHighPassFilter,
                                 kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                                 kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                 0,
                                 highPassFilterCutoff,
                                 0),
           "Coulnd't set kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency ");
```

I was trying like this...

```
-(IBAction)cutOffslider:(id)sender {
    [cutOffslider setMinimumValue:0.0];
    [cutOffslider setMaximumValue:6000.0];
     NSLog(@"SliderValue ... %d",(int)sender);
}
```

Output on debug console

```
PlayBasic[567:c07] cutOffSlider.value in effect 0.500000
```

How you can see I can obtain float value from slider, but when I increment or decrement the value by slider on simulator the effect won't change cutoff parameter. Any ideas for change parameter at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly this

```
NSLog(@"SliderValue ... %d", (int)sender);
```

is wrong. `Sender` is an object, the object that send the message: the UISliderView and this can't just be cast to an `int`

You need to connect the `(IBAction)cutoffSlider:(id)sender` to the UISliderView's action and then set the filter value in it like:

```
-(IBAction)cutOffslider:(id)sender {
    [cutOffslider setMinimumValue:0.0];
    [cutOffslider setMaximumValue:6000.0];
    NSLog(@"SliderValue ... %d",(int)sender);

    Float32 highPassFilterCutoff = cutOffslider.value;
    CheckError(AudioUnitSetParameter(_auHighPassFilter,
                             kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                             kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                             0,
                             highPassFilterCutoff,
                             0),
       "Couldn't set kHipassParam_CutoffFrequency ");
}
```

Comment: Tank you iain, just tonight i was undercover the mistake and i find the way by the same solution you are suggest! I think this is usefull for all community. great.... But if I can take advantage of your kindness i have i mysterious problem: i can start augraph and listen music from generator unit, but wen click stop augraph want resume: i need to restart app! any idea?

Comment: If you have another problem open another question